# Oracle SQL export to csv show error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

```
table_a                     table_b
--------------             ----------
product,amount,pcode      rounding,pcode
--------------             ----------
apple,100.00,001              0.02,001
orange,150.02,001            -0.02,001


output
----------   
apple,100.02
orange,150.00

select a.product||','||sum(a.amount)+b.rounding from table_a a,table_b b
where a.pcode=b.pcode
group by a.product,b.rounding
```

Hi , I trying to spooling this query to csv format, but showing error:

> ORA-01722 invalid number.

when I remove +b.rounding then no issued at all, may I know how to use sum(a.amount)+b.rounding in my query ?

your kinds assist is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with "export to csv" or with aggregation. You can reproduce it very simply, like this:

```
select 'a' || 1 + 3 as result from dual;

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

The reason is very simple: concatenation (the `||` operator) has the same precedence as addition (`+`). Since in your formula concatenation comes first, it is performed first. In my example, the number `1` is converted (implicitly) to the string `'1'` and concatenated to `'a'`, resulting in `'a1'`. Then this must be added to `3`. To do that, Oracle tries to convert `'a1'` (implicitly) to number, and obviously that fails, with the same error you observed.

If you expected the result to be the string `'a4'` (in my example), the solution is trivial: use parentheses.

```
select 'a' || (1 + 3) as result from dual;

RESULT
------
a4
```

The same applies to your situation.

Note that the following works - showing that `||` and `+` have the same precedence; concatenation is not **stronger than** addition, they are simply performed in order, left to right.

```
select 1 + 3 || 'a' as result from dual;

RESULT
------
4a
```

Here we don't need parentheses, because 1 + 3 = 4, and then that is converted to the string `'4'` and then `'a'` is concatenated to it.

Comment: Not that it matters, but - I just love reading your explanations.